# What are some beautiful but little-known proofs (or theorems)?

Tags: soft-question, big-list

I'm looking for examples of proofs (or theorems) which you find beautiful, but are not particularly well-known to undergrads, or people outside your area of expertise. Please also include a brief description of what the theorem says, and why either the theorem itself or its proof is beautiful.

I know this is a soft question and might get closed. I didn't see any similar questions on the site already, but if there are, I apologize.

Comment: Have you read [*Proofs from the Book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK)?

Comment: I'm unsure how well known this is. Let $S(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n (1/i) : 1 < n \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$ 
Then $S(n-1) > \log n > S(n) - 1.$  This is easily seen by interpreting $\log n$
as the area under the curve, represented by $\int_1^n (1/x) dx.$  It is easy to
set up *tall* rectangles, whose area $= S(n-1)$ that completely enclose the
region under the curve.  Similarly, you can set up *short* rectangles 
$\to [S(n) - 1]$ that are completely enclosed by the region under the curve.